# return rows IDs that causes the exception in oracle exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to return error message to user that explains the error with `rowid`s that caused the error using `raise_application_error()` in Oracle.

Example :

```
if v_test <0  then
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20040,
                         'Value must be greater than zero in rows number:!');
```

i.e : I want to specify rows numbers.

any idea please.

Comment: What variable hold the value of the id for the row? is that the primary key?

Comment: no its a unique column

Answer (score 0):

The error message is just a string, so you'd just include it in there:

```
if v_test <0  then
  Raise_Application_Error(
    -20040,
    'Value must be greater than zero in rows number: '||to_char(my_column) );
end if;
```